# How can I remove/cover up a section of a border?

Tags: html, css, border

How can I remove/cover up the 14px of border to the right of `main_right_article_pic.png`?

[image: MSA]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main_right_article">
<span class="main_right_article_left">
    <img src="img/main_right_article_pic.png" width="54" height="54" alt="Joe Bloggs">
</span>
<article>
    <h4>Joe Bloggs</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut mollis fringilla mi quis sollicitudin. Maecenas orci diam, congue eget sodales nec, facilisis eu eros.</p>
</article>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

div.main_right_article
{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 425px;
}

span.main_right_article_left
{
    float: left;
    background: url("../img/article_mark.png") no-repeat right 20px;
    height: 54px;
    width: 73px;
}

article
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #c9c9ca;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 330px;
}

article h4
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.3);
}

article p
{
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

**CSS:**

```
span.main_right_article_left
{
    float: left;
    height: 54px;
    width: 54px;
}

span.main_right_article_mark
{
    background-image: url("../img/article_mark.png");
    float: left;
    height: 14px;
    position: relative;
    right: -6px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 14px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main_right_article">
    <span class="main_right_article_left std_pic">
        <img src="img/main_right_article_pic.png" width="54" height="54" alt="Joe Bloggs">
    </span>
    <span class="main_right_article_mark">&nbsp;</span>
    <article>
        <h4>Joe Bloggs</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut mollis fringilla mi quis sollicitudin. Maecenas orci diam, congue eget sodales nec, facilisis eu eros.</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this issue with a tooltip in CSS.

See: http://csstooltip.com